# What about 2D-array indexes in C?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, indexing

I'm new in C programing and I need to use a 2D integer array (a matrix). For example, I do this:

```
void main(){
   int matrix[2][2] = { {0,1}, {2,3} };
   printf("%i", matrix[4][4]); /*Here should be an index error, but that doesn't happen*/
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with 2D indices, has it?

Comment: The compiler is not a replacement for a static analysis tool (although there is some overlap). You want a lint like tool, like Coverity's Quality Advisor (commercial) or splint (open source).

Answer (score 5):

> What is wrong?

What is wrong is your assumption about the compiler and/or the language. **C has no bounds checking.** The compiler won't warn you if you are accessing an array out of bounds.

What happens instead: your code is now invalid, it is said to invoke **undefined behavior,** and it's free to do anything it wants (including crashing or seemingly "working fine").

Answer (score 1):

This is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) unlike some other languages C does not do bounds checking and annex `J.2 Undefined behavior` of the [`C99 draft standard`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) gives this specific example:

> — An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the
>   given subscript (as in the lvalue expression a[1][7] given the declaration int
>   a[4][5]) (6.5.6).

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't perform bounds checking on array indices.  This can lead to off-by-one errors and buffer overflows, but it also allows your code to run faster.  As a C programmer, it is your responsibility to make sure that you only use valid indices.

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't have index errors, per say. It doesn't do index checks. In C, the programmer is the almighty know it all so everything you do is 'legal' in the sense that it will compile and run. When you do `matrix[4][4]` what is happening is undefined behavior. You're indexing somewhere on the stack and grabbing what ever is there and interpreting it as an int. If you try and access some ridiculous array bound as in `matrix[300][200]` you will more than likely get a segmentation fault.